# Render dynamic HTML using UI Library

Tags: angular, antd, dynamic-html

I'm using UI Library [Ant Design](https://ng.ant.design/docs/introduce/en) in Angular Project. I'm trying to render dynamic HTML inside but using UI library component, like this

My component.ts:

```
test : any;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.test = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml('<nz-table>
             <thead>
              <td>Header 1</td>
              <td>Header 2</td>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td>Value 1</td>
               <td>Value 2</td>
              </tr>
             </tbody>
            </nz-table>')
    }, 0);
}
```

My component.html:

```
<div [innerHtml]="test"></div>
```

But this is what I received

```
Header 1Header 2Value 1Value 2
```

So, how I can render dynamic HTML inside AntDesign's Nz-Table Component?

Comment: ```nz-table``` is an angular component not a native html tag. Look for how to dynamically render components in angular.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? maybe an `*ngIf` or `*ngFor` will solve your problem

Comment: @Zerotwelve i want render nzTable component with innerHTML is dynamic

Comment: sure it has to be dynamic. but why do you want to use innerHTML? this is not the way you usually do stuff in Angular. So what is your goal? Please edit your question with more details

Comment: @AmitKumar thank you for pointing out that for me. Thanks very much !

Comment: @Zerotwelve i want to render a dynamic table with unknown columns, but using ui library Ant Design

Comment: if you want dynamic column you can simply ```*ngFor``` inside ```thead```. i hope this is not your production project, that's not how you do things in angular.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use `innerHTML` but an `*ngFor`.
Your code example is very poor but I will do my best:

```js
const tableData = {
   headers: ["Header 1","Header 2"],
   rows: [
      ["row 1 value1","row 1 value2"],
      ["row 2 value1","row 2 value2"],
      ["row 3 value1","row 3 value2"]
   ]
}
```

in your HTML templare

```html
<nz-table>
<thead>
  <td *ngFor="let header of tableData.headers">{{header}}</td>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="values of tableData.rows">
      <td *ngFor="let value of values">{{value}}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</nz-table>
```

As you can see `tableData` can be anything, you can push row into it and the table will update. You can also get the value from an API or whatever you want.
You can also use JSON object instead of all this arrays and use keyvalue pairs if you want.

Comment: I considered this. But what i need is that i have a html string, and a i need render this html inside <nz-table> element. There're any solution for this ?

Comment: I don't think nz-table supports this. you can parse the string and extract the data from it, convert it and user the example above. There are many HTML parser that are easy to use.

Comment: Unfortunately, Antd is required in my project. If nz-table does not support this, maybe i will try another way. Thank you for taking time and your answer !